# What is the storage size required for a float(24) column with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqldatatypes

I ask because there are 2 different answers in the official documentation...

Is it 8 bytes? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

> A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.

Or 4 bytes? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric

> FLOAT(p): 4 bytes if 0 <= p <= 24, 8 bytes if 25 <= p <= 53

I think there is a mistake on the 1st page because float(24) require only 4 bytes of storage with PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server... So why MySQL do that differently?

Comment: I suggest you submit this as a documentation bug to MySQL, and see which one they fix.

Comment: Since the underlying format has 24 bits of binary precision (except during "gradual underflow"), 24 should be 4 bytes.  I tested it on 5.6; it is.  Note that when you use `FLOAT(30)`, then do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it shows that it was converted to `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

as @RickJames suggested - if you test using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` you can certainly see that `FLOAT(24)` is float, while `FLOAT(25)` is double.